# How to find the occurrence of comma in a report of txt format and replace it with space using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a many reports which is in a txt format in D:\folder\data\data1.The occurrence of comma is not predictable.Where ever the comma is found inside the txt file i need to replace with a space.so i have to do this for more than one text file

For example: The data in report will be like

```
abacndl      123455      300,90.55     aldfankas    400,123,455.900
adsmnfnka    12345774    134,789.9     aeraermk     456,987,87.000
```

and like wise it goes on

Could some one please help me in doing a batch script for this scenario

Comment: Are you sure you want to substitute space for each comma? Those look like thousands separators within one decimal number, in which case I should think you would simply want to remove the commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "line=%%b"
  >>"%%~na.XTX" echo(!line:,= !
 )
)
rem delete existing text files and renam new version to .txt
del *.txt
ren *.xtx *.txt
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

- change to the target directory,
- for each `.txt` file, read each line to `%%b`, save that in `line` for processing, and output `line` processed to substitute each `,` with <kbd>Space</kbd>

The name chosen for the new output file is `%%~na.xtx` - that is, the original name with a new extension `xtx`. In this way, you can easily check the new format before using. I'm assuming no `.xtx` files exist before the run.

---

I don't understand the problem with `del`/`ren` above; it works perfectly for me.

Here's another version - only the rename code is different.

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
PUSHD "%sourcedir%"
FOR %%a IN (*.txt) DO (
 FOR /f "usebackq delims=" %%b IN ("%%a") DO (
  SET "line=%%b"
  >>"%%~na.XTX" echo(!line:,= !
 )
)
rem rename new version to .txt - alternative codeline
FOR %%a IN (*.xtx) DO (MOVE /y "%%~na.XTX" "%%~na.txt") >nul
popd

GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! it perfectly works fine!! But I want to replace the comma with space and store in same text file.For instance, if i am trying to replace the comma in filename.txt i want to save the changes to the same file.It would be of great help if you can help me out in this

Comment: It's possible, but I'd not recommend it. The above modification should delete the old .txt and rename the new .xtx back to the old name.

Comment: Thank you!! I tried executing the above code its deleting all the text files and no files are available in the folder, no renaming is done back to the old file name. where am i going wrong? pls help

Comment: The `del` and `ren` commands work perfectly for me. Are you sure you used `reN *.xtx *.txt` and not `reM *.xtx *.txt` (which would be a comment.) `

Comment: Thanks alot!! It works fine now.But i encouter another problem with this code. This piece of code works on all text files except one text file. I could not understand on what reason it is not able to process that one specific file.Could you please help me out

Comment: Please edit the line(s) that are not processed correctly into your original question (just add it at the end as "lines not processed correctly). Without knowing what the line(s) are, it is just a guessing game.